# References are missing in .NET C# file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am missing references for a class. Earlier in Visual Studio 2022, the references in a class would show all the places it has been used. Now it shows what you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a solution (i.e., a *.sln file) open?

Comment: If you're asking about the difference between, say "- references" and "72 references", it'll show the dash whilst recomputing the references, and I believe it'll stay as a dash if everything is currently *badly broken* and not compilable.

Comment: its compilable and deployed in prod. Earlier it was working. Now its suddenly not working

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools->Options and search for codelens to open it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: i have tried this one. its enabled